# Opening links in a separate tab or window

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Currently links provided in questions or answers open in the same window. Can we tweak this a little so that the links opens up in a separate tab?

Comment: Something like this isn't within our purview, it's best to post this in http://meta.stackexchange.com.  But yeah, I agree that it would be a useful feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is better to post such questions (that affects whole the SE network) on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Visit similar question : [Make links posted by users open in a new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2275/260388) which has [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

The solution is : Just hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking on link or simply (mouse) middle clicking would work also.

Comment: Saw Keshav's note as well. Expecting users to work for a certain user experience is not a good idea but what can one do....

Comment: For a Mac, just Cmd+Click works :)

Comment: Someone on that thread makes an interesting point: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2278/236254 It's very difficult to make a link that's designed to open in another tab open in the same tab (something I hate), whereas it's relatively easy to make a link designed to open in the same tab open in a new tab.